# Magento 2: Shipping rates Not Change on Country Change

Tags: magento2

When I go to my checkout page and change country it's not reflecting my shipping rates.but on the cart page it's working how I debug this issue which files I need to check in magento2.

Comment: Can you please check in console any kind of error occur or not?

Comment: no error thats why debuging difficult

Comment: Any third party extensions you install after that this will happened?

Comment: after advance bundle js when i disable bundle js its work but i need bundle js as well

Comment: So, you need to check both code and competeble both one.
Both have some sort of code which generates the conflicts.

Comment: you have idea of advance bundle js so i share you my code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98724/discussion-between-mayur-and-imtiazau).

Comment: No, sir I don't have any idea but sometime one shipping method which is temendo that is also create confliction. So, try with disable that extension from file.

Comment: @imtiazau, hi how did you fix this issue? I'm looking for a solution to this problem. Please assist.